# Setting up custom color scale in R

Tags: r, colors, visualization

I am trying to setup a custom scale in R. My data ranges in values from -5.4 to +3.6 and I want to center the data around 0 (white). I would like a scale to the data such that I have the same number of gradations above and below 0 (I am shooting for 7 at the moment). The issue that I am having is that I can't get the scaling correct and I am not sure where my problem is.

My code at the moment (source data is in Pastebin link at the bottom):

```
   png('127-2_4_compare_other.png',width = 1200, height = 800, units = "px")
   colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))
   f <- function(m) t(m)[,nrow(m):1]
   colorBarz=matrix(seq(-5.5,4,len=15),nrow=1)
   colorBarx=1
   source("127-2_4.CompareMatrix.txt")
   colorBary=seq(-5.4,3.6,len=15)
   cus_breaks=c(-5.400, -4.725, -4.050, -3.375, -2.700, -2.025, -1.350, -0.675,  0.45, 0.90, 1.35, 1.80, 2.25, 2.70, 3.15, 3.60)
   layout(matrix(c(1,2), 1, 2, byrow = TRUE), widths=c(9,1))
   image(f(Compare2and4),axes=FALSE,ylab="Amino acids",xlab="Position",main="Sample 2 vs. 4",col=colfunc(15),breaks=cus_breaks)
   axis(1, seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.03703), labels=c(1:11,1:17))
   axis(2, seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.0526),labels=rev(c("A","R","N","D","C","E","Q","G","H","I","L","K","M","F","P","S","T","W","Y","V")),las=2)
   image(colorBarx,colorBary,colorBarz,col=colfunc(15),axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="log(Sample4 / Sample2)",breaks=cus_breaks)
   axis(2,las=2)
   dev.off()
```

I am looking for seven evenly split bins above 0 to 3.6 and seven evenly split bins below 0 to -5.4 and I would like 0 to hit in the middle of the white bin. Also if anyone can look over the heatmap code itself to make sure that there are no obvious errors I would greatly appreciate it. [Pastebin of the source data](http://pastebin.com/VZASGFw9)

[image: Heatmap correct scale incorrect]

Comment: not sure it will fix your problem but in such case I tend to bin the data (eg with `cut`) rather than the color palette.

Comment: If I understand cut correctly, that would help me set up bins of equal size above 0 and below 0. I think I have done the same here with the cus_breaks though I could be not looking at it correctly?

Comment: probably, this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301608/low-med-high-colors-for-deciles-in-ggplot

Answer (score 1):

A problem with your proposed color scale is that the perceptual distance between each point on the scale is not equal. The same color distance refers a larger range of data values on the positive end, compared to the negative end. I would suggest not reinventing the wheel, and making use of the great capabilities of `ggplot`.

By default, the diverging color scale will have white as the midpoint at value 0.

For example:

```
Compare2and4_t <- t(Compare2and4)[,nrow(Compare2and4):1]
am_ac <- c("A","R","N","D","C","E","Q","G","H","I","L","K","M","F","P","S","T","W","Y","V")
pdat <- data.frame(x = 1:nrow(Compare2and4_t), 
                   y = factor(rep(am_ac, each = nrow(Compare2and4_t)), levels = rev(am_ac)),
                   val = c(Compare2and4_t))

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(pdat, aes(x, y, fill = val)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = 'darkblue', high = 'darkred', 
                       limits = c(-5.4, 3.6), oob = squish) +
  coord_equal(expand = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(pdat$x)) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = 'Position', y = 'Amino acids')
```

[image]